# Created Document Comes up in Show Mongodb, Node.js, Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a Node.js app with Express.js and Mongodb and I'm having some trouble getting it to cooperate with me. The app is essentially a list of Recipes with it's ingredients. It works fine when I start the App. I can click to view a recipe and it shows the right one but the second I create a new one it seems to get "stuck" and the only recipe I'll see is the newly created one. But it shows the title to the right recipe on the top. Which is really confusing me.

Here's a Screenshot of what's happening if that helps at all. This is what's happening when I create an Eggs Benedict Recipe and click on the already existing "Chili" recipe:

[image: Issue]

Here's my Code:

Recipe_show.jade

```
h1= title
  div.recipe
    div.name= recipe.name
      - each ingredient in recipe.ingredients
        div.ingredient
          div.amount= ingredient.amount
          div.measurement= ingredient.measurement
          div.type= ingredient.type
```

recipeprovider.js

```
//find an recipe by ID
RecipeProvider.prototype.findById = function(id, callback) {

    this.getCollection(function(error, recipe_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
       recipe_collection.findOne({_id: recipe_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, 
        function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result)
    });
  }
});
```

};

app.js

```
// show individual recipes
app.get('/recipe/:id', function(req, res) {
    recipeProvider.findById(req.params.id, function(error, recipe) {
    res.render('recipe_show.jade', {
        title: recipe.name,
        recipe: recipe
    });
});
});
```

Comment: recipeprovider code is not correct ,you forgot all the {} around else keywords.

Comment: you are assuming findOne is returning a document but what if it's null ? then the rendering will fail